# PlayOnLinux не запускает игру

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Я пытаюсь установить wow legion пиратский от circle но при запуске выдает ошибку

```
Running wine-2.11-staging WoW Circle 7.3.5 - 32.exe (Working directory : /home/l4legenda/Документы/WoW Circle 7.3.5)
fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 2.11 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
fixme:winediag:start_process Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
err:module:load_builtin_dll failed to load .so lib for builtin L"winebus.sys": libudev.so.0: невозможно открыть разделяемый объектный файл: Нет такогоerr:winedevice:async_create_driver failed to create driver L"WineBus": c0000142
fixme:thread:create_user_shared_data_thread Creating user shared data update thread.
err:seh:setup_exception_record nested exception on signal stack in thread 0009 eip 7bcaddec esp 7ffdb940 stack 0x232000-0x330000
```

Подскажите что делать.

Comment: Ну чё-то с `winebus.sys` не то. Он установлен?

Comment: проблема что я не могу найти инфы как установить его. Или что либо с ним сделать.

Comment: Вайн из дистра или от разрабов вайна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как выяснилось тут было две проблемы. Первая это в PlayOnLinux. В нем не установлен нужный пакет. Проблема решилось запуском WoW через Wine напрямую. Но Wine 4.9 имеет баги с играми от blizard. Поэтому нужно установить Wine 4.6

> sudo apt-get install winehq-devel=4.6~bionic wine-devel=4.6~bionic wine-devel-i386=4.6~bionic wine-devel-amd64=4.6~bionic

После просто переходим в папку с игрой и запускаем игру

> wine WoW